# Difference between launchpad.net/ubuntu and packages.ubuntu.com?

Tags: package-management

What are the difference between launchpad.net/ubuntu and packages.ubuntu.com? Are they both for ubuntu packages?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. **http://packages.ubuntu.com/** provides  you information about all the packages available in the Ubuntu Package archive.

   Where you can **Search package directories** and **Search the contents of packages**
   Visit [About this site](http://packages.ubuntu.com/about/).
2. Whereas **Launchpad** is a unique collaboration and hosting platform for software projects.

   > It brings communities together — regardless of their choice of tools — by making it 
   >   easy to share code, bug reports, translations and ideas across projects.

   https://launchpad.net/ubuntu is registered by [“Ubuntu Technical Board” team](https://launchpad.net/~techboard) which support many things like:

   - [Report Bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug)
   - [Ask a question](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+addquestion)
   - Find Source code of project
   - [Distributing Software](https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/PPA)